# Removing Singularity of real bounded harmonic in punctured disk.

Tags: harmonic-functions, singularity

> If $u(z)$ is real harmonic and bounded in the punctured disk $0<|z-z_0|<R.$ Show that $\lim_{z\to z_0} u(z)$ exists.

I already know Complex analytic function $f$ which has singularity $z_0$ and bounded on some deleted neighborhood of $z_0$, Then $\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)$ exists and $f$ can be defined at $z_0$ so that it is analytic at $z_0$.

Comment: if $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the punctured disk and $Re(f(z))$ is bounded, do you get $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the whole disk ?

Comment: Punctured disk is not simply connected domain. So Analytic function $f$ with $Re(f(z)=u$ does not need to exist.

Comment: no. if $f(z)$ is analytic on the punctured disk but not at $z=z_0$, then $z_0$ is an isolated singularity, and by the classification theorem : $z_0$ is a pole or an essential singularity. in both cases $Re(f(z))$ is unbounded, so that $Re(f(z))$ bounded $\implies$ $f(z)$ is analytic on the whole disk.  $\quad$ note that you can also consider $g(z) = e^{-f(z)}$ which is analytic on the punctured disk and bounded on the whole disk, hence it is analytic on the whole disk (by [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity))